# unable to fetch data using Suspense and Await

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on using `Suspense` and `Await` in my React app. I'm using data loaders to load the data before the component is rendered.
When I simply use the loader function and the `useLoderData` function, I'm able to fetch the data. However, there is some delay in fetching the data so I want to defer the loader using `Suspense` and `Await`.

When I use this I only get some `Response` object.
[image]

Home.jsx

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { getBookmarks } from "./api";
import { useLoaderData, defer, Await } from "react-router-dom";

export function loader() {
  return defer({ bookmarks: getBookmarks() });
}

export default function Home() {
  const dataPromise = useLoaderData();

  function renderBookMarks(bookmarks) {
    console.log(bookmarks);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome to bookmarks</h2>
       <Suspense fallback={<h2>Loading...</h2>}>
        <Await resolve={dataPromise.bookmarks}>
          {renderBookMarks}
        </Await>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}
```

api.js

```js
import config from './config'

const apiUrl = config.apiUrl;
const apiPort = config.apiPort;

const joinUrl = (baseUrl, url) => {
  return ${baseUrl}/${url}
}

const domain = ${apiUrl}:${apiPort}/api/bookmarks;

export async function getBookmarks(url = "") {
  url = joinUrl(domain, url)
  const data = await fetch(url);
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the `fetch` response object, but you probably also want to unpack the response object, these days typically JSON.

Example:

```js
export async function getBookmarks(url = "") {
  url = joinUrl(domain, url);
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, got it. Wonder why it worked when i just called this getBookmarks() in the loader function without defer.

Comment: @manjosh Yeah, it's indeed subtle. From what I can tell, when you are not deferring the loading of data I believe the route loader functions are able to directly return the Response object and automagically call `response.json()`. When you return a `defer` you are not directly returning a Response object. See the [Returning Responses](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader#returning-responses) section of the loader docs that may explain this better than I just have. Seems odd it couldn't/wouldn't just work the same in both cases.